# Are there any Kinesis Connectors for Python DataStream API Flink 1.13 version?

Tags: python, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, pyflink, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am trying to build a streaming application using Kinesis Data Analytics with Flink 1.13 version in Python.

The source for the application is the Kinesis data stream.

but I can see that the kinesis connector FlinkKinesisConsumer is not available in Flink 1.13(PyFlink) version.

Are there any other way to connect with Kinesis Data Stream using the Python Data Stream API using Flink 1.13 version?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Flink locally (not part of Kinesis Data Analytics), you can download the connector from Maven: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-sql-connector-kinesis

Currently the connector version you would need for AWS supported latest Flink version would be version 1.13.2 scala version 2.12.

To help facilitate development of Flink applications, AWS also provides Kinesis Data Analytics Studio which provides an Apache Zeppelin notebook environment. This may be a good starting point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SX_6x_wXIfA